# Warning "Value is never used as Publisher" in Mockito code. Can one suppress it?

Tags: java, mockito

Is there any chance of avoiding

> Value is never used as Publisher

in IntelliJ IDEA in cases like this one:

```java
doReturn(Mono.just(something)).when(monoSupplier).get(); // get is highlighted
```

Is there any "magic string" I can pass to `@SuppressWarnings`, for example?

Also, I don't want to disable the warning altogether

## UPD

Kudos to Jonasz, but it's worth pointing out that `when()` doesn't always help

```java
        String userString = "user", admingString = "admin";
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> roles = Stream.of(userString, admingString).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken testAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                null, null, roles
        );
        ServerWebExchange exchangeMock = mock(ServerWebExchange.class);
        when(exchangeMock.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(Mono.just(testAuthentication));
```

[image]

I guess it's some IntelliJ bug, 'cause sometimes it *does* help

```java
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationFake = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principalName, null);
        ServerWebExchange exchangeMock = mock(ServerWebExchange.class);
        when(exchangeMock.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(Mono.just(authenticationFake));
```

[image]

Aren't the two code snippets essentially the same when it comes to that inspection?

## UPD2

Look, now it's gone. The code's the same. Go figure

[image]

On second thought, maybe the warning appeared in the first place because I imported the wrong `when()`. Specifically

```java
import static reactor.core.publisher.Mono.when;
```

instead of

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress the warning you should use `"ReactiveStreamsUnusedPublisher"` value passed to the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation:

```java
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("ReactiveStreamsUnusedPublisher")
void suppression() {
    doReturn(Mono.just("something"))
            .when(monoSupplier)
            .get();
}
```

Another option is to use `when` and `thenReturn` methods from the Mockito API - the suppression is not needed as the warning does not appear:

```java
@Test
void whenThenReturn() {
    when(monoSupplier.get())
            .thenReturn(Mono.just("something"));
}
```

Both solutions result in no warning displayed by IntelliJ:

[image: both methods in Intellij]

Comment: Thanks! Where do you get those strings for `@SuppressWarnings`? Can I see the list? How did you know what you needed to pass? The lists I saw on the internet are short and only cover the basics, like "unchecked"

Comment: IntelliJ simply suggests that within the warning inspection, but I own an Ultimate version of the application, it may be not available in the Community edition. Regarding the list of the strings, try for example here: https://jazzy.id.au/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html (yet the list is old and incomplete I think, the full list seems to be an IntelliJ internal).

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot to show where exactly you found that string? I also have the Ultimate version, but I don't see it anywhere, including in the inspection description

Comment: I click the Alt+Enter shortcut with cursor on the `get`, then I select the inspection and there's the suprression (it may be added on different levels: method, class etc.): https://i.imgur.com/VvsAuTR.png